# Program in C keep seg faulting with asm function

Tags: c, x86, header, segmentation-fault, nasm

I have a simple C program with a function I built in intel assembly that multiplies a number by the other and then returns the product of the two after that I use `printf` to output the number. I used a Makefile to assemble and link the files. Heres the Makefile:

```
output: main
main: multiply.o
    gcc -g -m32 resources/multiply.o main.c -o main

multiply.o:

    nasm -f elf32 resources/multiply.asm -o resources/multiply.o
```

The header file for the function is:

```c
#ifndef MULTIPLY_H

    #define MULTIPLY_H
    int multiply(int x,int y);
#endif
```

The C file is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_library/multiply.h"

int main(){
    int result = multiply(5,6);
    printf("%i",result);
    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly for the function is

```
global multiply

multiply:
    push ebp 
    mov ebp,esp 
    mov eax,[ebp+8] ;arg2
    mov edx,[ebp+12] ;arg1
    mov ebx,0 ;prepping the counter
    sub edx,1
    mov ecx,eax ;saving arg1
    loop_s:
        cmp ebx,edx ;comparing ebx to edx, if ebx >= edx, break out of the loop
        jge loop_e

        add ebx,1
        add eax,ecx

        jmp loop_s
    loop_e:
    mov ebx,0 ;reset ebx to it's initial state (before the loop)
    mov edx,0
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp
ret
```

I expected to get the value 30 but instead I got a segmentation fault
It appears to break at

```
0x56556050 <printf@plt>
```

Program receives the signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Here are the registers after the seg fault

```
eax            0xffffe030          -8144
ecx            0x5                 5
edx            0x0                 0
ebx            0x0                 0
esp            0xffffccfc          0xffffccfc
ebp            0xffffcd28          0xffffcd28
esi            0xffffcdf4          -12812
edi            0xf7ffcb80          -134231168
eip            0x56556050          0x56556050 <printf@plt>
eflags         0x10292             [ AF SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x63                99
```

Here are the registers before

```
eax            0x1e                30
ecx            0x5                 5
edx            0x0                 0
ebx            0x0                 0
esp            0xffffcd10          0xffffcd10
ebp            0xffffcd28          0xffffcd28
esi            0xffffcdf4          -12812
edi            0xf7ffcb80          -134231168
eip            0x565561fb          0x565561fb <main+47>
eflags         0x282               [ SF IF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43/
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x63                99
```

When doing `mul edx`, I get the same SIGSEV segmentation fault
What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: `mov ebx,0 ;reset ebx to it's initial state` are you very sure of that? Why don't you `push ebx; push edx; ... pop edx; pop ebx;` ? Aside the final `mov esp,ebp` should be unnecessary.

Comment: I would write it in assembly as :        `mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        ret`

Comment: 32-bit PIC/PIE code will typically use EBX as a pointer to the GOT, and as an anchor for referencing static data.  It's call-preserved in the calling convention but your code trashes it.  It might be the PLT entry itself that faults if it assumes the caller has EBX pointing to the GOT, otherwise you're probably passing a bad format string address to printf.